High Low Range Sequence of Order Requirements
Pine Script Noob....I have an established high/low range during a specific time range, which sets the daily trade bias.  Trade trigger is a break of the range and a reversal cross of the 200ema.  Problem is that the only trades that are executed in the strategy tester are when the 200ema are outside of the high/low range.  I'd like the break of the range to trigger the trade bias, but the position of the 200ema cross be irrelevant.  Help is appreciated.  Cheers.
I've set up a sequence of conditions, but having issues.  problem code below.
// Positions management
if (condition1_long and condition2_long and strategy.position_size == 0 and hour >= start_trading_hour and hour <= end_trading_hour)
strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
strategy.exit("Long", loss = stop_loss_in_ticks, profit = take_profit_in_ticks, comment_loss = "SL Long", comment_profit = "TP Long")
